# How to replace NA in a large raster with values from another raster in R?

Tags: r, replace, raster

I have two large raster images (30,000 x 30,000), one for the year 2000 another for 2005. I want to replace the pixels with NA in the 2000 raster with their respective non-NA values from the 2005 raster. Here is an example:

```
r1 <- raster(ncols=36, nrows=18)
r1[] <- 1:ncell(r1)
plot(r1)
r2 <- raster(ncols=36, nrows=18)
r2[] <- 1:ncell(r2)
r2[r2<300] <- NA
plot(r2)
```

In this example I would like to replace the NA's in "r2"  by their respetive values in "r1". I tried the command "cover()" in R but that one does not complete "r2," rather it returns the info that is missing in "r2" but present in "r1":

```
r2.fix <- cover(r2, r1)
plot(r2.fix)
```

Any ideas on how the job done? Thank you in advance.

UPDATE: The problem with this solution:

```
r2[is.na(r2)] <- r1[is.na(r2)]
```

Is that it does not work with large rasters. R returns the following error:

```
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 2.6 Gb
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In order(cells[, 2]) :
  Reached total allocation of 16080Mb: see help(memory.size)
```

Comment: If your rasters are too big, check out this [guide](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/raster/vignettes/functions.pdf) on writing functions for large rasters, particularly block-wise processing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce your problem only with large raster.
I have **Error: cannot allocate vector of size 6.7 Gb** with 16GB RAM.
You need to change the *chunksize* in the *Session options*.

[From Introduction to the ’raster’ package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/raster/vignettes/Raster.pdf)

> The options chunksize and maxmemory
>   determine the maximum size (in number of cells) of a single chunk of values that
>   is read/written in chunk-by-chunk processing of very large files.

Comment: Thanks Arkaiy, your approach would work with small rasters, but with large ones that solution runs into memory problems. This is what I got: Error: cannot allocate vector of size 2.6 Gb
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In order(cells[, 2]) :
  Reached total allocation of 16080Mb: see help(memory.size)

Comment: You need to change the chunksize in the Session options.